# Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from a use of ‘endpoints’

Tags: plutus, haskell

I'm writing emulator trace tests for the spacebudz contracts. Here is a minimum example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules  #-}

module Test.EmulatorTrace where

import           Control.Monad           hiding ( fmap )
import           Control.Monad.Freer.Extras    as Extras
import           Data.Default                   ( Default(..) )
import qualified Data.Map                      as Map
import           Ledger
import           Ledger.Ada                    as Ada
import           Ledger.TimeSlot
import           Ledger.Value
import           Plutus.Contract.Trace
import           Plutus.Trace.Emulator         as Emulator
import           PlutusTx.Prelude
import           Prelude                        ( IO
                                                , Show(..)
                                                )
import           Wallet.Emulator.Wallet

import           Contract


test :: IO ()
test = do
  test'

test' :: IO ()
test' = runEmulatorTraceIO' def def myTrace

myTrace :: EmulatorTrace ()
myTrace = do

  h1 <- activateContractWallet (Wallet 1) endpoints
  callEndpoint @"init" h1 ()

  void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 10
```

However, when trying to activate the wallets for the emulator, I get this error:

```
src/Test/EmulatorTrace.hs:45:43: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from a use of ‘endpoints’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Wallet.Types.AsContractError
                                  e0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘e0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        two instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘activateContractWallet’, namely
        ‘endpoints’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        h1 <- activateContractWallet (Wallet 1) endpoints
      In the expression:
        do h1 <- activateContractWallet (Wallet 1) endpoints
           callEndpoint @"init" h1 ()
           void $ waitNSlots 10
   |
45 |   h1 <- activateContractWallet (Wallet 1) endpoints
```

How is it possible, when every contract example has the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because you're not specifying where the `endpoints` variable comes from. So, basically the error is saying: You've various instances of `endpoints` variable, which of those is it?

Try to specify it on your imports, something like this:

`import OffChainCode (endpoints)`

And if your offchain code is in the `Contract` file, try to change the name of the module Contract, as it's a Plutus type.

Answer (score 0):

This is changed in newer versions so you need to change:

```
h1 <- activateContractWallet (Wallet 1) endpoints
```

to

```
h1 <- activateContractWallet w1 (endpoints @ContractError)
```

For w1 you need to import `Plutus.Contract.Test` and for ContractError `Wallet.Types`

Answer (score 0):

I think your endpoint looks something like this

```
endpoints :: forall  e. AsContractError e => Contract () yourSchema e ()
```

now in TraceMonad its confused what type should we put for variable e.

if you change your endpoint definition  to

```
endpoints :: Contract () yourSchema Text ()
```

This worked fine for me as now we are passing concrete types for endpoint.